# Craft 3 Multi Site - Entries/categories/assets fields aren't translatable?

Tags: craft3, multi-site

I'm testing out the Craft 3 beta's multi-site capability at the moment to see if it's suitable for an upcoming project.

My sample scenario is a school that runs out of multiple countries. They offer the same courses, but may want to tailor the content for different countries.

If we want different tutors assigned per site (country) to this course, we can't as an entries field (pulling from teachers section) is not translatable/multi site capable.

We run into the same problem with using matrix fields for content. We generally have a general content matrix field that allows the client to build their content with different pre-defined blocks (side by side images, text with image, full width text, video etc. etc.). But matrix fields aren't translatable either.

Same for images etc. There are a few other scenarios where this would raise its head just in this one example.

For this feature to be usable for how we use Craft, we'd need multi site support on those field types. Is this something that's coming or should I start thinking of another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we want different tutors assigned per site (country) to this course, we can't as an entries field (pulling from teachers section) is not translatable/multi site capable.
>
> …
>
> Same for images etc.

All relational field types (Assets, Categories, Entries, Tags, and Users) have a “Manage relations on a per-site basis” setting (under Advanced). If you check it, each site will get its own set of relations.

[image: The advanced settings for Entries fields]

> But matrix fields aren't translatable either.

Same - Matrix fields have a “Manage blocks on a per-site basis” setting, right below the big Configuration setting.

[image: Matrix setting]